# How-to: Create role instances on emulator

Tags: azure, emulation, roles

How do I create new instances of some role via C# using Azure emulator? Is there some guide about that? There are some manuals about creating instances in the cloud, not in emulator.

So far I know that:

- I need to change config-file. Is it config in sln-file or in some temp-delpoyment folder?
- I need to use csrun tool. How to pick params?

**UPD**
Got it.

To change count or instances on emulator, you have to:

- update 'ServiceConfiguration.cscfg' file in bin-folder
- run 'csrun' tool with params: `string.Format("/update:{0};\"{1}\"", deploymentId, "<path to ServiceConfiguration.cscfg>")`

where deploymentId:

```
    // get id from RoleEnvironment with regex 
    var patternt = Regex.Escape("(") + @"\d+" + Regex.Escape(")");
    var input = RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId;
    var m = Regex.Match(input, patternt);
    var deploymentId = m.ToString().Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty);
```

If you have troubles running csrun via code, read this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/62ca1372-2388-4181-9dbd-8fbba470ea77

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In local emulator, you need to modify the CSCFG file under the deployment .csx folder, instead of your source code folder, since the local emulator will fire your application up from that folder.

Once you modified the saved your CSCFG file, for example the count of the instances you can retrieve the new value from your code immediately. But if you want the local emulator detect this changes and perform the related actions, such as increase the VMs or invoke the Configuration_Changed method, you need to execute 
csrun /update:;

You can retrieve the deployment id from the compute emulator UI.

Comment: Looks like the WIKI engine removed the csrun command, it should be like this /update:<DeploymentId>;<ConfigurationFile>

Comment: Shaun Xu, how can I get <DeploymentId> (RoleEnvironment.DeploymentID?) and full path to <ConfigFile> (This file is in some deployment folder. How I can get full path to it?).

Comment: The deployment id you can get from the Compute UI, on the tree in left hand side you can see Service Deployments > deployment16(4), for example on my desk. The "4" is the deployment id. The configuration file path, might be changed in SDK 1.6, it should be under your azure project folder > bin > Debug > ServiceConfiguration.cscfg.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the instance count in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg in your Azure project